# How to display most frequently ordered product by each user?

Tags: sql

Let's say we have a table

```
User   Product  Frequency
A       P1         5
A       P2         4
A       P3         3
B       P1         3
B       P2         4
C       P1         2
C       P2         1
```

and i want the result to be displayed like:

```
User   Product  Frequency
A       P1        5
B       P2        4
C       P1        2
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: which sql engine are you using?

Comment: @zealous I am using Mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number` to assign a rank by frequency per user. following solution should work if you are using SQL server, MySQL 8.0, Oracle, PostgreSQL.

you can use `rank()` as well.

```
select
  user,
  product,
  frequency
from
(
  select
    *,
    row_number() over (partition by user order by frequency desc) as rn
  from yourTable
) subq
where rn = 1
```

Comment: what if i use Rank() function in place of row_number?

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach that could be applied is:

```
Select user, product, frequency from
(select t.*,  max(t.frequency) OVER (PARTITION BY t.user) max_frq
from tab t) where frequency = max_frq;
```

Another approach is by row_number:

```
Select usr, product, freq from(
Select t.*, row_number() OVER (Partition by usr order by freq desc) rn
from tab t)
where rn = 1;
```

Rank():

```
Select usr, product, freq from (
Select t.*, rank() OVER (Partition by usr order by freq desc) rn
from tab t
)where rn = 1;
```

Dense_rank():

```
Select usr, product, freq from(
Select t.*, dense_rank() OVER (Partition by usr order by freq desc) rn
from tab t
)where rn = 1;
```